# Selecting a native-base `<Select>` option using Playwright

Tags: reactjs, react-native, playwright, native-base

I am trying to use Playwright to select a Native-Base `<Select>` option, but I don't know how to reference the HTML `<select>` input created by this component.

My React Native code looks like this:

```js
<Select
  testID="nb-select-component"
  defaultValue="yes"
>
  <Select.Item label="Yes" value="yes" />
  <Select.Item label="No" value="no" />
</Select>
```

This renders in HTML as something like this:

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <input readonly type="hidden" data-testid="nb-select-component" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the `testID` propagates into an `<input readonly />` element, not to the `<select>` element.

If I could grab the `<select>` HTML element, my Playwright code would look something like this:

```js
const selectElement = page.locator("data-testid=html-select-element");
await selectElement.selectOption({ "value": "yes" });
```

However I don't know how to access the `<select>` HTML element or change the value of the `<Select>` native-base component from Playwright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playwright supports XPath queries, so if I isolate the `<input data-testid="nb-select-component" />`, I can use Xpath to retrieve the `<select>` element from the grandparent's `<div>` like this:

```js
const selectElement = page.locator(
  '//input[@data-testid="html-select-element"]' + // xpath to <input>
  '../../select' // grandparent's first child: <select>
);
await selectElement.selectOption({ "value": "yes" });
```